# Woocommerce breadcrumbs multiple categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I have e commerce website in wordpress. There are lot of product in it & many product comes under multiple categories like 600 mah Power bank is comes under automobile, IT, media etc. My problem is when i go to the detail of a product there it by default pick up only one category no matter if go through IT category at the end it shows me automobile like this Home / Shop / industry / Automobile / 600 mah Power Bank. But i went to this product via IT so it should show me like this Home / Shop / industry / IT / 600 mah Power Bank. 
How can iget path where i come from previous page?

Comment: So the product is in 2 categories? There's no way for `get_categories()` to know which category you think it should display.

Comment: @helgatheviking if i go selecting automobile it should show automobile & for same product if i go selecting IT it should show IT

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand, but my best guess would be: on the category page, add a parameter to the product URLs to identify their source. ex: `mysite.com/product/some-product?src=automobile`. Then when on the single product page for "some product" check for that `$_GET` variable and use it to set the breadcrumb.

Comment: To add to @helgatheviking's idea. make sure when you're passing through the `$_GET` variable back to display that you're sanitizing the input before displaying it to the screen or you'll open your site up to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using Woocommerce you can use the following directly, if not it will need adapting but you get the idea:

```
if (get_post_type() == 'product' && is_single() && ! is_attachment()) {
    echo $prepend;

    if ($terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat')) {
        $referer = wp_get_referer();
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $referer_slug = (strpos($referer, $term->slug));

            if ($referer_slug == true) {
                $category_name = $term->name;
                $ancestors = get_ancestors($term->term_id, 'product_cat');
                $ancestors = array_reverse($ancestors);

                foreach ($ancestors as $ancestor) {
                    $ancestor = get_term($ancestor, 'product_cat');

                    if (! is_wp_error($ancestor) && $ancestor) {
                        echo $before . '<a href="' . get_term_link($ancestor->slug, 'product_cat') . '">' . $ancestor->name . '</a>' . $after . $delimiter;
                    }
                }
                echo $before . '<a href="' . get_term_link($term->slug, 'product_cat') . '">' . $category_name . '</a>' . $after . $delimiter;
            }
        }
    }

    echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
}
```

The main bulk of the work here is done by `wp_get_referer` which gets the referring URL of the product your visitor has navigated to. The rest of the code checks if a valid category is contained within the URL and uses it in the breadcrumb.

See Jonathon Js post here for more information http://www.cryoutcreations.eu/forums/t/wrong-breadcrumbs-displayed

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer for anyone still encountering this issue on a newer version of WooCommerce, this solution worked for me on WooCommerce 3.5.4.

This code should be placed inside the following file path (i.e. a child theme)
/wp-content/themes/your-child-theme/woocommerce/global/breadcrumb.php

It will override the default WooCommerce breadcrumb code.

http://pastebin.com/raw/bemM8ZNF

```
/**
 * Shop breadcrumb
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/global/breadcrumb.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.3.0
 * @see         woocommerce_breadcrumb()

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( $breadcrumb ) {

    echo $wrap_before;

    if ( is_single() && get_post_type() == 'product' ) {

        echo $prepend;

        if ( $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) ) {

            $referer = wp_get_referer();

            $printed = array();

            foreach( $terms as $term){

                if(in_array($term->id, $printed)) continue;

                $referer_slug = (strpos($referer, '/'.$term->slug.'/'));

                if(!$referer_slug==false){

                    $printed[] = $term->id;

                    $category_name = $term->name;
                    $ancestors = get_ancestors( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' );
                    $ancestors = array_reverse( $ancestors );

                    foreach ( $ancestors as $ancestor ) {
                        $ancestor = get_term( $ancestor, 'product_cat' );

                        if ( ! is_wp_error( $ancestor ) && $ancestor )
                            echo $before . '<a href="' . get_term_link( $ancestor->slug, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $ancestor->name . '</a>' . $after . $delimiter;
                    }

                    echo $before . '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $category_name . '</a>' . $after . $delimiter;
                }
            }

        }

        echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } else {

        foreach ( $breadcrumb as $key => $crumb ) {

            echo $before;

            if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
                echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) . '">' . esc_html( $crumb[0] ) . '</a>';
            } else {
                echo esc_html( $crumb[0] );
            }

            echo $after;

            if ( sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
                echo $delimiter;
            }

        }
    }

    echo $wrap_after;

}
```

C/O: Joris Witteman

Comment: I've just tried this but getting two errors: " Undefined variable: post" and "Trying to get property of non-object in breadcrumb.php" on line 25.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I reworked the code a little bit to account for a primary category and a referred one, having infinite parents.

I used the breadcrumb filter as it is quite clean, directly in the single product template, but in case you need it elsewhere you can use the single conditional.

```
function breadcumbs_referred_or_primary ($main, $terms)
{
  // Our primary term is 520 (hardcoded)

  $referer = wp_get_referer();
  $referredTerm = -1;
  $referredTermIndex = -1;
  $primaryTermId = 520; // hardcoded
  $primaryTermIndex = -1;

  foreach($terms as $key => $term) {
    if ($referredTerm != -1) break; // we found it in a previous iteration!

    $ancestors = get_ancestors( $term->term_id, 'product_cat');
    array_unshift($ancestors, $term->term_id);
    if ($primaryTermIndex == -1 && in_array($primaryTermId, $ancestors)) $primaryTermIndex = $key;

    foreach ($ancestors as $ancestor) {
      if($referredTerm != -1) break 2; // we found it in a previous iteration!
      $ancestor = get_term( $ancestor, 'product_cat' );
      $referer_slug = (strpos($referer, '/'.$ancestor->slug.'/'));

      if (!$referer_slug==false) { // it's found in the current level
        $referredTerm = $term->term_id;
        $referredTermIndex = $key;
      }
    }
  }

  // we return either the browsed terms or the primary term
  if ($referredTermIndex != -1) {
    return $terms[$referredTermIndex];
  } else {
    return $terms[$primaryTermIndex];
  }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_breadcrumb_main_term', 'breadcumbs_referred_or_primary', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. However, you need to replace `$referredTermIndex` with `0` at the end:  `else { return $terms[0]; }`, because there is an error if there isn't a referer (direct Product access)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {

    echo $wrap_before;

    if (is_single() && get_post_type() == 'product') {
        $breadcrumb_diff = [];
        $breadcrumb_diff[] = $breadcrumb[0];
        if ($terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat')) {
            $referer = wp_get_referer();
            $site_url = site_url();
            $referer = str_replace($site_url . '/zoomagazin/', '', $referer);
            $referer_array = explode('/', $referer);
            foreach ($referer_array as $term_slug) {
                $get_term_by_slug = get_term_by('slug', $term_slug, 'product_cat');
                $breadcrumb_diff[] = [$get_term_by_slug->name, get_term_link($term_slug, 'product_cat')];
            }
            $breadcrumb_diff[]= $breadcrumb[count($breadcrumb) - 1];

            foreach ($breadcrumb_diff as $key => $crumb) {

                echo $before;

                if (!empty($crumb[1]) && sizeof($breadcrumb_diff) !== $key + 1) {
                    echo '<a href="' . esc_url($crumb[1]) . '">' . esc_html($crumb[0]) . '</a>';
                } else {
                    echo esc_html($crumb[0]);
                }

                echo $after;

                if (sizeof($breadcrumb) !== $key + 1) {
                    echo $delimiter;
                }

            }
        }
    } else {


        foreach ($breadcrumb as $key => $crumb) {

            echo $before;

            if (!empty($crumb[1]) && sizeof($breadcrumb) !== $key + 1) {
                echo '<a href="' . esc_url($crumb[1]) . '">' . esc_html($crumb[0]) . '</a>';
            } else {
                echo esc_html($crumb[0]);
            }

            echo $after;

            if (sizeof($breadcrumb) !== $key + 1) {
                echo $delimiter;
            }

        }
    }

    echo $wrap_after;

}
```